# Dynamically filling selectbox + jQuery UI sortable reset

Tags: jquery-ui, list, dynamic, jquery-ui-sortable, drop-down-menu

I have a selectbox which takes its option values from a `<ul>` list. The list is changeable via jQuery UI sortable functionality, and the selectbox dynamically updates as you sort items differently.

I have made that functionality, the code is dirty but it does the job:
http://jsfiddle.net/trunkadelic/TtnTf/2/

What I need is a "reset" function, which brings the list (and thus, the selectbox) back to their original values. I am not sure how to approach this, even a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page load I would store off the initial state of the list in a JavaScript variable.  Then, when the reset link is clicked I would restore the state of the `<ul>` to what it was on page load.  From there you can use the same method you already have to update the selectmenu to match.

I forked your jsFiddle to show this - http://jsfiddle.net/g8GLw/